# Because I have data in the output of standard error with some git commands?

Tags: python, git

If `ret` is 0, then because I have data on the standard error output (stderr)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import call

f = open('/tmp/err.log','wb')
ret = call[(['git', 'checkout', 'master'], stderr=f)
if ret == 0: print 'Success!'
```

This occurs in some git commands. In this example I am already in the master branch.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a clear question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having trouble fully grasping your question but I think you are asking

"If I get a return code of 0 why do I have data in stderror" I would edit the question but I am honestly not sure.

The answer to what I think your question is: stderror does not necessarily mean there was an error in the command.

For example, fetching with the --progress flag git will send the output to stderror

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html

Comment: You're right. Now I understood. The error code returned by the 'call' command only denotes that the command syntax is correct.

Comment: Cool, glad it made sense. Mind accepting the answer?